# Aapt package takes more time with the latest android build tool version 23.0.3

Tags: android, gradle, build, aapt, build-tools

Aapt packaging with the android build tool version 23.0.2 and 23.0.3 takes almost twice the time it takes with build tool version 23.0.1.

What could be the reason ? And how to solve it?